# .NET Core 2.0 - Http client accept header not recognized

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient, request-headers

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1");

Is there any bug related to how you should add a accept header to a request?

This is a request for a specific payment gateway in Brazil (pagseguro). I've already posted in their forums  but none of the members seems to be using .NET Core there yet.

Message I get: Accept header is mandatory

Comment: Link to reference and reason for the problem for .NET Core 3.1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64545309/2112736

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json"));

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("charset=ISO-8859-1"));
```

> **DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept** is a collection of string type, where you can add your header to accept using the new instance of MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.

Comment: httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

The line above seemed to resolve. The two following ones were not valid accept headers according to c# compiler, so I kept the previous one:

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1");